# add icon to exe file ,when exe file dont have resource section

Tags: c, windows, resources, icons, exe

how can add  icon to exe file when that exe file  dont have resource section?

exe file dont have resource section because it configured for tininess

my coding  environment is c/c++ in windows

some suggestion and hit  please

this code is work when PE file have resource section:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/ICON_Resources.aspx?display=Print
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/UpdateResource.aspx

Comment: you can't do that without a resource section AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Icons are stored in the resource section; you need one to store an icon.

Comment: Yes, recompile without disabling the resource section.

Comment: after add new empty section  we use begin update  ! now i solve it

Comment: We dont need to create resource section , when work with resource  API  section is created auto  so you simply use resource  function